# How to handle special characters in LaTeX?

Tags: verbatim, characters

I am working on one file which has some special chacters.

```
    König IR   : KA}unig ,K ~ A}unig 
%          : Comment in latex (so no text after this %)
-          : escape
```

I get different output which seems to be very funny. How can i handle such characters in LaTeX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\makeatletter 
%\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\fontfamily{ua1}\selectfont}  % verbatim in Arial
% \makeatother 
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
König IR   : KA}unig ,K ~ A}unig 
%          : Comment in latex (so no text after this %)
-          : escape
\end{verbatim}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{2cm} @{\,:\,} l }
König IR   & KA\}unig ,K \textasciitilde\ A\}unig \\
\%         & Comment in latex (so no text after this \%)\\
-          & escape
\end {tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and the same with arial for verbatim:

[image]

Comment: I am using same but its font type is different from other. I am using Arial in whole text but when i use verbatim, font type enclosed in this tag is different and there is one space before and after of this tag while i am not using any space.

Comment: I am using code \begin{verbatim} 
Helgadottir A, Thorleifsson G, Manolescu A, Gretarsdottir S 
\end{verbatim}   But there is one line space before and after the text. Why?

Comment: give a _complete_ example of what you did. I have no crystal ball ...

Comment: \documentstyle[html]{article}   

\textbf{[1] PMID:20622881} 
 \begin{verbatim} 
Gretarsdottir S, Baas AF, Thorleifsson G, Holm H 
\end{verbatim} 
\textbf{\emph{ Genome-wide association study identifies a sequence variant within the DAB2IP gene conferring susceptibility to abdominal aortic aneurysm. }} 
  Nat. Genet. 2010 07 11; 42(8) 



\end{document}

Comment: use `\verb|Gretarsdottir S, Baas AF, Thorleifsson G, Holm H|` instead. However, using `documentstyle` is from the last century ... You should use `\documentclass`

Comment: This is just a dummy report.In my real report i am using documentclass.

Comment: I noticed font type of \verb is different from other. I am using Arial font type but font type seems to be different. How can i change font size to Arial for this text?

Comment: `\verb` sets all in a typewriter font. If you do not like it, then redefine the original definition: `\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ttfamily}` (see my edited answer)

Comment: I am using    cat("\n","\\def\\verbatim@font{\\normalfont\\fontfamily{arial}}","\n") before text still i am getting same typewriter font.

Comment: there is no font family arial, it is named `ua1`. See my edit, how it must be used.

Comment: then accept the answer, otherwise your question will be listed as unanswered ...