# How to handle % character in LaTeX?

Tags: verbatim, characters

I am working on special character handling and my text is having % as one the special character which is treated as comment and anything after that is not printed. I m using verb as suggested in my previous thread but still pblm.

[How to handle special characters in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58717/how-to-handle-special-characters-in-latex)

Below is my code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ua1} 
This is my sample text for checking % character. I found whereever there   is     % character it is treated as comment and nothing gets printed after this. How can i fix this pblm. I m using verb still getting same pblm. pls help me how can i fix this pblm.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not only do you need to define/set the `verbatim` font, you need to select/use it in a `verbatim` environment (say).

Comment: Are you really want to use `%` in some code lising? If this is only a normal text, just use `\%`. And you may need to read a short but complete LaTeX tutorial first.

Answer (score 9):

To typeset verbatim material you need to use, for example, the `verbatim` environment (in your code snippet you only selected a font for verbatim material) and manually introduce line breaks (I commented out some lines because I don't have `uarial.sty`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
%\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
%\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ua1} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
This is my sample text for checking % character. I found 
whereever there  is  % character it is treated as comment 
and nothing gets printed after this. How can i fix this pblm. 
I m using verb still getting same pblm. pls help me how 
can i fix this pblm.
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `fancyvrb` packages offers more possibilities and enhanced verbatim environments/commands; the `listings` package extends even more the possibilities.

If all that you need is to typeset the percentage character, use `\%`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
%\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
This is my sample text for checking \% character. I found whereever there   is   \% character it is treated as comment and nothing gets printed after this. How can i fix this pblm. I m using verb still getting same pblm. pls help me how can i fix this pblm.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: using \begin{verbatim} \end{verbatim} generates no newline and output text is in typewriter output format so i cannot use it.

Comment: @manish then simply write `\%` (with a backslash).

Comment: @manish: What do you mean by "newline". Do you want an automatic line-break? Inside `verbatim` everything is typeset as-is. Sure you can change the font to whatever you want, but it doesn't do line-breaks.

Comment: @manish I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Werner apparently all that is required is how to typeset `%` in normal text.